# Enums defined with Array Constant in java

Tags: arrays, enums

I'd like to know if it is possible to define an enum with an Array as a constant; see the following code excerpt.

This does not compile with an illegal start of expression error. May anyone help me?.

Many thanks

```
public enum Currency
{
    *****PENNY(1, {"one", "oneone"}),*
    NICKLE(5, {"five"}),
    DIME(10, {"ten"}),
    QUARTER(25, {"twentifive"});****

    private int valueInteger;
    private String[] valueString;

    private Currency(int valueInteger, String[] valueString) {
        this.valueInteger = valueInteger;
        this.valueString = valueString;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you'll just need to initialize them.  For example,

```
NICKLE(5, new string[]{"five"})
```

Answer (score 0):

For this use case, I would use a vararg approach instead:

```
public enum Currency {
    PENNY(1, "one", "oneone"),
    NICKLE(5, "five"),
    DIME(10, "ten"),
    QUARTER(25, "twentifive");

    private int valueInteger;
    private String[] valueString;

    private Currency(int valueInteger, String... valueString) {
        this.valueInteger = valueInteger;
        this.valueString = valueString;
    }

}
```