# define a Set as an enum constant

Tags: java, enums, static

Is this possible ?

```
public enum Device_Type{
    enuminstance1(constant1,constant2,...,constantN);

    public Set<String>  String_set;

    public Set<String> getSet(){
       return this.String_set;
}
```

if so, how would one get-into the static initialization to create the set?

```
enuminstance1(Setconstant1);
```

Comment: Same thing goes for just array constants: String[]

Comment: this has an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8614399/enums-defined-with-array-constant-in-java

Comment: So you got your answer?

Comment: yes! I'm quite new to SO